# make two columns as unique in sqlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, unique-constraint

I have one table with 3 columns. columns are

```
BaseColumns._ID | NATIVE_CONTACT_ID | HIDDEN_TYPE
```

in these, `BaseColumns._ID` is a primary key. What I want is, I don't want to allow developer to insert a duplicate value into `NATIVE_CONTACT_ID`, if he tries to insert, then old value of `HIDDEN_TYPE` column value corresponding to `NATIVE_CONTACT_ID` should be overriden with new value.

Let me clarify you more. for example, my table looks like this after few insertions.

```
_ID  | NATIVE_CONTACT_ID | HIDDEN_TYPE
---------------------------------------
  1        23                 1
  2        24                 0
  3        25                 1
  4        26                 0
```

Now when developer wants to insert a new row with `NATIVE_CONTACT_ID` having value 25 and having `HIDDEN_TYPE` value `0`, then old value of `HIDDEN_TYPE` should change to this new value. here it should change to `0` from `1`, I don't want to allow duplicate insertions of `NATIVE_CONTACT_ID`.

I hope I explained my problem clearly.

Now my question is, What are the keywords and SQL statement I need to use to create a such table?

This is what I have tried...

```
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "hidden_info";
    public static final String HIDDEN_TYPE = "hidden_type";
    public static final String NATIVE_CONTACT_ID = "native_contact_id";
    public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
                + NATIVE_CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER, " + HIDDEN_TYPE
                + " INTEGER)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE name (column defs, UNIQUE (NATIVE_CONTACT_ID) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
```

For more information please see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

Comment: I have tried your answer. but it is inserting a new row with new value. for exapmle, My table is having a row with NATIVE_CONTACT_ID value = 4 and HIDDEN_TYPE value = 1, now when I insert a new row with NATIVE_CONTACT_ID = 4 and HIDDEN_TYPE = 0, it inserts a new row instead of replacing old value...

Comment: Thanks dude... I have solved my problem. Just I made only `NATIVE_CONTACT` column as UNIQUE. instead of `UNIQUE(NATIVE_CONTACT_ID,HIDDEN_TYPE)`, I used `UNIQUE(NATIVE_CONTACT_ID)`...

Comment: please edit your answer. Sure I will accept it... :-)